# Can i detect popup position change?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, popup

I have a problem when using wpf popup,that is:

### how can I know the popup change it's position?

For example:

I have a popup,its placement set to bottom, when i move the the window to the a corner, the placement change to top,actually it does not.I debug it according to the popup opened event.
all I want to know it how I can know it change,so i can transform the tip background! thanks.

you can see the demo pictures here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxOVl.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWEAQ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case the popup is always on a window (not a page).
I solved it by registering to the Window events: LocationChanged and SizeChanged:

```
        Window w = Window.GetWindow(this);
        if (w != null)
        {
            w.LocationChanged += windowLocationChanged;
            w.SizeChanged += windowLocationChanged;
        }
```

To realign the popup with the window(or controls in it) I use the following trick:

```
        if (!_popup.IsOpen)
            return;

        if (_popup.VerticalOffset == 0.1)
            _popup.VerticalOffset = 0;
        else
            _popup.VerticalOffset = 0.1;
```

Setting the VerticalOffset triggers the re-alignment of the popup, and the small value keeps it within pixel boundaries.

Comment: i think you misunderstand my question,what i want is to know when the popup change it's position.--- When i get this,i can start my animation to transform the background,which the arrow point to the correct direction.--- i don't care Window's LocationChanged!

Comment: In case your popup does not stay open, then it is simple: use the popupOpened event and in there get its coordinates and the coordinates of the target control and do the math.

If the Popup stayopen as I assumed that was your case then you do care about WindowSizing and Location changes.

Comment: thank you! i know what you mean. Actually i just think it is complicated to compute the coordinates, don't u think so? i have to know the position of the target control to compute the height it stay away from my desktop....has some other simple ways?

Comment: Every UIElement has TranslateToPoint function. I once had to solve a similar problem as you described. I used Border with rounded corners and a a simple V-shaped Path with a name, that was placed a litle bit over the border so that its border was not visibile in that spot.  In the PopupOpened-event I used TranslateToPoint relative to the Window to calc the coordinates of both elements (Popup and its target).